# WPF ComboBox: при выборе элемента или щелчке вне комбобокса оставить Popup открытым

Tags: c#, wpf

Стандартное поведение КомбоБокса такое, что при выборе элемента или щелчке где-нибудь вне КомбоБокса открытый список закрывается. Причем, если щелкнуть на какой-нибудь кнопке вне комбобокса, то при первом щелчке закроется Popup, и только при втором сработает кнопка. Поведение не очень удобное, особенно если это Touch-интерфейс.

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891680/wpf-combobox-click-outside-of-popup-suppress-mouse-click?noredirect=1&lq=1) нашел, как обойти второе поведение с кнопкой. Вроде неплохо работает. Я "подвешиваю" этот код на событие DropDownClosed. Правда, если щелкнуть на самом КомбоБоксе (это ведь тоже Button, только ToggleButton), то возникает исключение "Cannot reopen a popup in the closed event handler". Это понятно, так как находимся "внутри" события. Пробовал еще в событии SelectionChanged применить, безрезультатно, так как после SelectionChanged все равно происходит DropDownClosed.

Может есть у кого-нибудь идеи, как можно обойти это исключение и не дать закрыться списку? Может в другом событии попробовать?

Comment: может чем превозмогать штатное поведение `ComboBox`, просто воспользоваться другими стандартными контроллами, `ListBox` внутри `Expander` например -- чем вас не устраивает?

Comment: Интересно. Спасибо за подсказку